# How to reduce the unit testing running time?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit5

I'm using Eclipse and doing java code unit testing, but my unit testing running time taking a long time. Is there is any way to reduce the unit testing running time????

My project based on AWS S3 buckets and java. I am using java 8 and junit5 and i did the function move, copy, delete the single file and multiple files transaction functions. So I was checked that functions were correctly worked or not using junit5. but my unit testing taking a long times.

Comment: You need to provide more data. What is the test about? Does execution of your program (not the test) also take time... Also please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Will be helpful

Comment: My project based on AWS S3 buckets and java. I am using java 8 and junit5 and i did the function move, copy, delete the single file and multiple files transaction functions. So I was checked that functions were correctly worked or not using junit5. but my unit testing taking a long times.

Comment: Is it a single test that takes a long time or the whole suite? Essentially the broad options are run less tests, or, run tests in parallel.

Comment: One class has six functions. Those functions parallelly run unit test and i used @AfterEach also.

Comment: Speeding up software in general is a very broad topic - it starts from buing faster hardware and ends at the optimization of specific software functions.  One could write a book to answer your question.  You need to be more specific.